# SSE2 - 16-byte aligned dynamic allocation of memory

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++-2005, memory-alignment, sse2

**EDIT:**

This is a followup to [SSE2 Compiler Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874882/sse2-compiler-error)

This is the **real** bug I experienced before and have reproduced below by changing the `_mm_malloc` statement as [Michael Burr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876433/sse2-16-byte-aligned-dynamic-allocation-of-memory/1876448#1876448) suggested:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00415116 in SO.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading 
>   location 0xffffffff.

At line `label: movdqa xmm0, xmmword ptr [t1+eax]`

I'm trying to dynamically allocate `t1` and `t2` and [according to this tutorial](http://www.developers.net/intelisnshowcase/view/116), I've used `_mm_malloc`:

```
#include <emmintrin.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{ 
 int *t1, *t2;
 const int n = 100000;
 t1 = (int*)_mm_malloc(n*sizeof(int),16);
 t2 = (int*)_mm_malloc(n*sizeof(int),16);
 __m128i mul1, mul2;
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
  {
  t1[j] = j;
  t2[j] = (j+1);
  } // set temporary variables to random values
  _asm
  {
   mov eax, 0
   label: movdqa xmm0, xmmword ptr [t1+eax]
   movdqa xmm1, xmmword ptr [t2+eax]
   pmuludq xmm0, xmm1
   movdqa mul1, xmm0
   movdqa xmm0, xmmword ptr [t1+eax]
   pshufd xmm0, xmm0, 05fh
   pshufd xmm1, xmm1, 05fh
   pmuludq xmm0, xmm1
   movdqa mul2, xmm0
   add eax, 16
   cmp eax, 100000
   jnge label
  }
     _mm_free(t1);
     _mm_free(t2);

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the 2nd problem is that you're reading at an offset from the pointer variable (not an offset from what the pointer points to).

Change:

```
label: movdqa xmm0, xmmword ptr [t1+eax]
```

To something like:

```
mov ebx, [t1]
label: movdqa xmm0, xmmword ptr [ebx+eax]
```

And similarly for your accesses through the t2 pointer.

This might be even better (though I haven't had an opportunity to test it, so it might not even work):

```
  _asm
  {
   mov eax, [t1]
   mov ebx, [t1]
   lea ecx, [eax + (100000*4)]

   label: movdqa xmm0, xmmword ptr [eax]
   movdqa xmm1, xmmword ptr [ebx]
   pmuludq xmm0, xmm1
   movdqa mul1, xmm0
   movdqa xmm0, xmmword ptr [eax]
   pshufd xmm0, xmm0, 05fh
   pshufd xmm1, xmm1, 05fh
   pmuludq xmm0, xmm1
   movdqa mul2, xmm0
   add eax, 16
   add ebx, 16
   cmp eax, ecx
   jnge label
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

You're not allocating enough memory:

```
t1 = (int*)_mm_malloc(n * sizeof( int),16);
t2 = (int*)_mm_malloc(n * sizeof( int),16);
```

Comment: Sorry, stupid mistake. But that's not the **real** problem. I've updated it now to reproduce the bug I had difficulty with

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
t1 = (int*)_mm_malloc(n*sizeof(int),16);
```